# Block videos in android webview - Alternative to shouldInterceptRequest()

Tags: java, android, webview

I have created a web browser using webview in android. My aim is to control the content of the webview before it is loaded. Whenever the content of the webview makes a request to any domain server, it has to pass through [shoulInterceptRequest()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29). If the url is pointing to any video uploading sites(youtube.com, vimeo.com), I can change it to some Access Denied url so that video will not be loaded.

```
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, String url) {
        try { 
            if (access.permission(url)) {
                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return getResponseData();
    }

    private WebResourceResponse getResponseData() {
        try {
            String str = "Access Denied";
            InputStream data = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            return new WebResourceResponse("text/css", "UTF-8", data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But [shoulInterceptRequest()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) is availabe from API 11. I NEED it to work from API 8.

Is there any alternative way to implement it ? I need to block the url if it is potinting to any video uploading sites BEFORE LOADING ANY DATA.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String) event?

You can block the url and then call http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl(java.lang.String) to show anything you want (and even run arbitrary javascript with the "javascript:do_something()" notation)

Comment: shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is only for the main url that is loaded into the webview. That is, webview.loadUrl(www.example.com). If www.example.com contains a video, log doesn't show that url. It always shows www.test.com in shouldOverrideUrlLoading